# How to cancel all tasks in a TaskGroup

Tags: python, python-asyncio

```
import asyncio
import random

task_group: asyncio.TaskGroup | None = None

async def coro1():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("coro1")

async def coro2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            print("dead")
            assert task_group is not None
            task_group.cancel() # This function does not exist.
        else:
            print("Survived another second")

async def main():
    global task_group
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        task_group = tg
        tg.create_task(coro1())
        tg.create_task(coro2())
    task_group = None

asyncio.run(main())
```

In this example, `coro1` will print "coro1" every second, `coro2` has a 10% chance to cancel the entire `TaskGroup`, i.e., cancel both `coro1` and `coro2` and exit the `async with` block every second.

The problem is I don't know how to cancel the task group. There is no `TaskGroup.cancel()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I end up use another task to wrap the function that contains the TaskGroup and cancel that task instead. It works as desired.

```
# Only show functions that has been changed

main_task: asyncio.Task[None] | None = None

async def coro2():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if random.random() < 0.1:
            print("dead")
            assert main_task is not None
            main_task.cancel()
            main_task = None
        else:
            print("Survived another second")

async def main2():
    global main_task
    main_task = asyncio.create_task(main())

asyncio.run(main2())
```

Answer (score 3):

While `asyncio.TaskGroup` does not come with an exposed API to cancel all tasks, the [source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/616fcad6e2e10b0d0252e7f3688e61c468c54e6e/Lib/asyncio/taskgroups.py#L185) shows that you can simply call the `_abort` method of a task group to cancel all of its undone tasks:

```
if random.random() < 0.1:
    print("dead")
    assert task_group is not None
    task_group._abort()
else:
    print("Survived another second")
```

Comment: It gave me a red underline and the following warnings in VSCode:
`Cannot access member "_abort" for type "TaskGroup"`
  `Member "_abort" is unknown`.
But when actually run it regardless of the warning. It did work. I misinterpreted the warning as `_abort()` is unknown while what it means is the return type of `_abort()` is unknown. But the first warning means we should avoid accessing it if we follow the rules strictly, so I will still pick my answer as it complies with the more strict rules, but I apologize, your answer does work.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to use TaskGroup's internal function `_abort` or wrap main function inside another main you can do the following:

```py
import asyncio
from asyncio import Task
from random import random


async def job_1(tasks: list[Task]):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)  # Work that is being done
        if random() < 0.1:  # When every task should get cancelled
            for task in tasks:
                if task == asyncio.current_task():
                    print("Task 1 cancelling others first")
                    continue
                if task.done():
                    print("Some task was already done")
                    continue
                task.cancel()
            return
        print("Task 1")


async def job_2(tasks: list[Task]):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        if random() < 0.1:
            for task in tasks:
                if task == asyncio.current_task():
                    print("Task 2 cancelling others first")
                    continue
                if task.done():
                    print("Some task was already done")
                    continue
                task.cancel()
            return
        print("Task 2")


async def daemon():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        print("Daemon task")


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as group:
        tasks: list[Task] = []
        task_1 = group.create_task(job_1(tasks))
        task_2 = group.create_task(job_2(tasks))
        daemon_task = group.create_task(daemon())
        tasks.append(task_1)
        tasks.append(task_2)
        tasks.append(daemon_task)


asyncio.run(main())
```